# Why is windows displaying a question mark on system.out.print in java?

Tags: java, encoding, command-line, cmd, println

I've written a program in java on a ubuntu-machine.

Everything was fine until I tried to run the program on my windows machine...
big misstake =D

All `System.out.print("String");` where not displayed correctly. Then I tried to let windows ONLY print `System.out.print("");`

The windows cmd outputs `?`

Full code would be:

```
import java.io.*;
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.print("");
    }
}
```

What on earth is this???
I really didn't enter any ? or other characters to print out...

Comment: Actually, the only answer I can give to your question is `?`.  So I don't blame your Windows system.  :) Seriously, we need some more code to go on than just one print statement.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for tips on creating a minimal example.

Comment: There is no more code than this actually... just the main class and method =D

Comment: The `?` is a replacement character for a char which cannot be displayed in a given charset. However I have no idea why it would be printed in your case. Did you recompile the source or used the class file? Can you check the source for any hidden broken hex characters (or just write it new with no cut+paste).

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake myself...

I still wonder about it, but the clue is:

The document was written in UTF-8.
After converting the code to ANSI, some mysterious signs appear.

`System.out.print("ï»¿o");`

Oooookay... don't know what this is, or what sense it makes?

But I got my code running =)

Comment: That is a zero-width non-breaking space. There was no problem with your encoding - in fact, treating the file as ANSI (when it's not ANSI) messed up your code by converting the zero-width non-breaking space into garbage characters (although that might be a good thing in this case, since it let you solve your problem).

Comment: I'd say that if you're looking at a computer program and it looks like the program says `System.out.println("");`, when in fact there are characters inside the quotes, then you're using the wrong tool for viewing/editing programs.

Comment: `ï»¿`, in other words the byte sequence `0xEF`, `0xBB`, `0xBF` constitutes `UTF-8` [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)